# Facebook How to submit App Review for user_events permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As all of you know, **Facebook** has reset and close a lot of permissions on `Graph API` since **Cambridge Analytica**.

Recently **Facebook** has re-opened their API access with **app review process**. For the review process, we would like to submit "`user_events`" permission.

But the problem is to demonstrate how we are using this permission with Screencast because we currently cannot get access to "`user_events`" even with test users.

So how should we record screencast for "`user_events`" permission to submit app review?

Comment: Of course you can “get it”, with any user that has a role in your app, as long as the app is in dev mode ...

Comment: Snarky much? This was literally broken up until the day Steve asked. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/852732598261025/

Comment: Are you found the solution? I face the same problem

Comment: @IdhamPerdameian The API endpoint is sadly disabled now it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have changed since the questions was asked.

Current status:

> This edge is only available to a limited number of approved apps. Unapproved apps querying this edge will receive an empty data set in response. You cannot request access to this edge at this time.

[developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/)